# Prove that there exists a simple path of length $1$ or $2$ from $u$ to $v$

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph with $|V|=17$ and $\forall v\in V\quad \deg(v)\geq 8$.
>   Prove that for every $v,u \in V$ there exists a simple path of length $1$ or $2$, which starts with $u$ and ends with $v$.

*Progress*:
By contradiction, assume there exist $u,v\in V$ for every simple path from $u$ to $v$ (let it be $S$) with $3\leq |S|$ or $0=|S|$. I don't see what I can do here, since $0=|S|$ looks true.

Tried building a simple path with no success as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assume the graph is simple.  Then $u$ connects to at least $8$ other vertices, leaving at most $8$ that it does not connect to.  If $v$ is among the vertices $u$ connects to, we are done.  Otherwise $v$ connects to at least $8$ other vertices.  There are only seven others that do not connect to $u$, so it must connect to one of the vertices that does connect to $u$.

Answer (score 0):

The closed [neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) of $u$ and $v$ both contain $\geq 9$ vertices.  Since the number of vertices is $17 < 2 \times 9$, these two closed neighborhoods intersect.

*Note*: We need to also assume $u \neq v$ for the theorem to be correct.